# Run log4j on jamvm

Tags: java, log4j, jamvm

Trying to run simple java application with log4j on jamvm virtual machine:

```
jamvm -cp ".:log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:log4j-core-2.11.2.jar" m.main
```

Got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:90)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:59)
   at java.lang.reflect.VMConstructor.construct(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:319)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1154)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:94)
   at m.main.<clinit>(main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Objects not found in java.lang.ClassLoader$1{urls=[file:/opt/rfidSrv/./,file:/opt/rfidSrv/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar,file:/opt/rfidSrv/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar], parent=null}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:531)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:341)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1112)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:293)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:90)
   ...6 more
```

What is wrong there and how to fix that?

The same command on Oracle Java works fine:

```
java -cp ".:log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:log4j-core-2.11.2.jar" m.main
```

Code:

package m;

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class main {
    private static final Logger LOG =  LogManager.getLogger(main.class);
     
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        LOG.info("---startting---");
        
        LOG.debug("This Will Be Printed On Debug");
        LOG.info("This Will Be Printed On Info");
        LOG.warn("This Will Be Printed On Warn");
        LOG.error("This Will Be Printed On Error");
        LOG.fatal("This Will Be Printed On Fatal");
 
        LOG.info("Appending string: {}.", "Hello, World");
        
        }
}
```

Comment: What Java JRE are you using? The missing class appeared in Java 7.

Comment: I' not sure, I got system with already installed jamvm